# Wearing tzitzis touching the skin

Tags: halacha, tzitzis

Am I allowed to wear wool tzitzis touching the skin (meaning no undershirt)?
Please send the makor also

Comment: I would think the default assumption would be yes and you would have to prove otherwise, not the other way around.

Comment: The tzittzit are attached to an article referred to as a "beged", or garment, how would it be forbidden to wear a garment against your bear skin?

Comment: I Once heard that it's not kavod for the tzitzis to be touching the skin... that's why I'm asking

Comment: "kavod for the tzitzis", the tzitzis don't touch the skin, the garment does